# Does a herbivore gain 1 star if he attacks but the damage is ignored due to armor plating?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

This scenario came up in a game played tonight:

1. The King is in Tokyo City and has an Armor Plating card ("Ignore
   damage when that damage would only make you lose 1").
2. Alienoid is not in Tokyo and has a Herbivore card ("Gain 1 star on your turn if
   you don't damage anyone").
3. Alienoid, after his second and final reroll, has rolled a single Attack (along with a few hearts).  We all agreed that The King should not take any damage because of his Armor Plating.

Our question:  Should Alienoid gain 1 star since he didn't damage anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, Alieniod with Herbivore should gain 1 Star for not damaging anyone.**

Herbivore specifically tells you to gain a Star if you don't damage anyone, so assuming Alienoid doesn't buy a card that damages anyone, they will gain 1 Star from **Herbivore**. The [rules specifically](http://www.iellogames.com/download/KOT-US-Rules-low.pdf) call out the matter:

> If an attack somehow ends up doing no damage (due to Camouflage for example), then it is no longer considered an attack for the purposes of cards like Poison Spit or **Herbivore**.